# SQL Syntax Error Near Where Statment On UPDATE Function

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, where-clause

Ok so I don't understand whats going on. To my knowledge the code is right but its throwing an SQL Syntax error which is odd because I use this same code all over my sites. I was hoping someone could look over it let me know if there are any errors that they see. Thank you.

The error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=954001' at line 1

The Code:

```
<?php session_start(); //!!!!Nothing Can Go Before Me!!!!
require_once('***********');
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

//INFO UPDATE//
$her_name = $_POST['her_name'];
$her_pic_url = $_POST['her_pic_url'];
$his_name = $_POST['his_name'];
$his_pic_url = $_POST['his_pic_url'];
$event_date = $_POST['event_date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$event_address = $_POST['event_address'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$her_about = $_POST['her_about'];
$her_fb = $_POST['her_fb'];
$her_twit = $_POST['her_twit'];
$him_about = $_POST['him_about'];
$him_fb = $_POST['him_fb'];
$him_twit = $_POST['him_twit'];
$userpic_1 = $_POST['userpic_1'];
$usercap_1 = $_POST['usercap_1'];
$userpic_2 = $_POST['userpic_2'];
$usercap_2 = $_POST['usercap_2'];
$userpic_3 = $_POST['userpic_3'];
$usercap_3 = $_POST['usercap_3'];
$userpic_4 = $_POST['userpic_4'];
$usercap_4 = $_POST['usercap_4'];
$userpic_5 = $_POST['userpic_5'];
$usercap_5 = $_POST['usercap_5'];
$userpic_6 = $_POST['userpic_6'];
$usercap_6 = $_POST['usercap_6'];
$userpic_7 = $_POST['userpic_7'];
$usercap_7 = $_POST['usercap_7'];
$userpic_8 = $_POST['userpic_8'];
$usercap_8 = $_POST['usercap_8'];
$userpic_9 = $_POST['userpic_9'];
$usercap_9 = $_POST['usercap_9'];
$userpic_10 = $_POST['userpic_10'];
$usercap_10 = $_POST['usercap_10'];
$userpic_11 = $_POST['userpic_11'];
$usercap_11 = $_POST['usercap_11'];
$userpic_12 = $_POST['userpic_12'];
$usercap_12 = $_POST['usercap_12'];
$userpic_13 = $_POST['userpic_13'];
$usercap_13 = $_POST['usercap_13'];
$userpic_14 = $_POST['userpic_14'];
$usercap_14 = $_POST['usercap_14'];
$userpic_15 = $_POST['userpic_15'];
$usercap_15 = $_POST['usercap_15'];
$userpic_16 = $_POST['userpic_16'];
$usercap_16 = $_POST['usercap_16'];
$userpic_17 = $_POST['userpic_17'];
$usercap_17 = $_POST['usercap_17'];
$userpic_18 = $_POST['userpic_18'];
$usercap_18 = $_POST['usercap_18'];
$userpic_19 = $_POST['userpic_19'];
$usercap_19 = $_POST['usercap_19'];
$userpic_20 = $_POST['userpic_20'];
$usercap_20 = $_POST['usercap_20'];
$userpic_21 = $_POST['userpic_21'];
$usercap_21 = $_POST['usercap_21'];
$userpic_22 = $_POST['userpic_22'];
$usercap_22 = $_POST['usercap_22'];
$userpic_23 = $_POST['userpic_23'];
$usercap_23 = $_POST['usercap_23'];
$userpic_24 = $_POST['userpic_24'];
$usercap_24 = $_POST['usercap_24'];
$userpic_25 = $_POST['userpic_25'];
$usercap_25 = $_POST['usercap_25'];

$insert = "UPDATE ******* SET her_name = '$_POST[her_name]', her_pic_url = '$_POST[her_pic_url]', his_name = '$_POST[his_name]', his_pic_url = '$_POST[his_pic_url]', event_date = '$_POST[event_date]', time = '$_POST[time]', event_address = '$_POST[event_address]', email = '$_POST[email]', her_about = '$_POST[her_about]', her_fb = '$_POST[her_fb]', her_twit = '$_POST[her_twit]', him_about = '$_POST[him_about]', him_fb = '$_POST[him_fb]', him_twit = '$_POST[him_twit]', userpic_1 = '$_POST[userpic_1]', usercap_1 = '$_POST[usercap_1]', userpic_2 = '$_POST[userpic_2]', usercap_2 = '$_POST[usercap_2]', userpic_3 = '$_POST[userpic_3]', usercap_3 = '$_POST[usercap_3]', userpic_4 = '$_POST[userpic_4]', usercap_4 = '$_POST[usercap_4]', userpic_5 = '$_POST[userpic_5]', usercap_5 = '$_POST[usercap_5]', userpic_6 = '$_POST[userpic_6]', usercap_6 = '$_POST[usercap_6]', userpic_7 = '$_POST[userpic_7]', usercap_7 = '$_POST[usercap_7]', userpic_8 = '$_POST[userpic_8]', usercap_8 = '$_POST[usercap_8]', userpic_9 = '$_POST[userpic_9]', usercap_9 = '$_POST[usercap_9]', userpic_10 = '$_POST[userpic_10]', usercap_10 = '$_POST[usercap_10]', userpic_11 = '$_POST[userpic_11]', usercap_11 = '$_POST[usercap_11]', userpic_12 = '$_POST[userpic_12]', usercap_12 = '$_POST[usercap_12]', userpic_13 = '$_POST[userpic_13]', usercap_13 = '$_POST[usercap_13]', userpic_14 = '$_POST[userpic_14]', usercap_14 = '$_POST[usercap_14]', userpic_15 = '$_POST[userpic_15]', usercap_15 = '$_POST[usercap_15]', userpic_16 = '$_POST[userpic_16]', usercap_16 = '$_POST[usercap_16]', userpic_17 = '$_POST[userpic_17]', usercap_17 = '$_POST[usercap_17]', userpic_18 = '$_POST[userpic_18]', usercap_18 = '$_POST[usercap_18]', userpic_19 = '$_POST[userpic_19]', usercap_19 = '$_POST[usercap_19]', userpic_20 = '$_POST[userpic_20]', usercap_20 = '$_POST[usercap_20]', userpic_21 = '$_POST[userpic_21]', usercap_21 = '$_POST[usercap_21]', userpic_22 = '$_POST[userpic_22]', usercap_22 = '$_POST[usercap_22]', userpic_23 = '$_POST[userpic_23]', usercap_23 = '$_POST[usercap_23]', userpic_24 = '$_POST[userpic_24]', usercap_24 = '$_POST[usercap_24]', userpic_25 = '$_POST[userpic_25]', usercap_25 = '$_POST[usercap_25]', WHERE id=$id";

$result=mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

if ($result) {
header("location:**********");
}

else {
echo "Whoops! There seems to have been an error! Please try again! If the problem persists please contact Modern Event Productions to update your event!<a href='***************'>Click here to go back to the Vendor System and try again.</a>";
} ?>
```

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: After " usercap_25 = '$_POST[usercap_25]') " you have a , which should be removed because " usercap_25 = '$_POST[usercap_25]', WHERE... " is invalid.
And you should protect your database from SQL injections.

Comment: This could be done so much easier with a loop/implode as well.

Comment: Take the **generated sql** (as that is the only thing of importance to answer the question) and look at it. Does it run if you try it in the MySQL CLI client? If not, why not? (Break down the problem into parts.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`,WHERE id=$id`

It is telling you the SQL statement is incorrect and the problem is the `WHERE` clause of the statement.

get rid of the `,`

Answer (score 2):

The last element in the set clause contains a trailing comma that is just before `WHERE`.

Removing that comma ',' before the `WHERE` clause should clear the error.